# AngularJS - Spring security config issue

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-security, spring-boot

I am trying to configure spring security for a AngularJS web app using Spring Boot.

I have created a custom login page and configured as below. Seems some problem in the mapping but not sure where.

**Angular route**

```
var mdmApp = angular.module("mdmApp");

mdmApp.config(function($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {

    console.log("Calling Login route...");

    $routeProvider

    .when("/login", {
        templateUrl : "4_security/login.html",
        controller : "loginController"
    })

    .otherwise("/login");

    // For Spring security
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
})
```

**Spring Security config**

```
@Configuration
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
protected static class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
                // Login
                .formLogin()

                // Login url
                .loginPage("/login")
                // Failure url
                .failureUrl("/login?error")

                .and()

                .authorizeRequests()

                // Permit these resources
                .antMatchers("/login", "/4_security/login.html", "/bower_components/**", "/1_reportingEntities/*.js", "/2_dataCollections/*.js",
                        "/3_calendar/*.js", "/error", "/")
                .permitAll()

                // Other requests
                .anyRequest().authenticated()

                .and()

                // CSRF protection
                .csrf().csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository()).and().addFilterAfter(csrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);
    }
```

**login.html**

```
    <div ng-app="mdmApp">

    <form name="loginForm" role="form" novalidate="novalidate">

        <br>
        <p class="heading">Login</p>
        <br>

        <div class="alert alert-danger" ng-show="error">Invalid Credentials. Please try again.</div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2 required">Username</label>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <input type="text" name="username" ng-model="credentials.username" class="form-control" required="required">
            </div>
            <div class="error" ng-messages="loginForm.username.$error" ng-if="loginForm.username.$touched">
                <div ng-message="required">Required field</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2 required">Password</label>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <input type="password" name="password" ng-model="credentials.password" class="form-control" required="required">
            </div>
            <div class="error" ng-messages="loginForm.password.$error" ng-if="loginForm.password.$touched">
                <div ng-message="required">Required field</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <br>

        <div class="row">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="login()">Login</button>
            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary">Reset</button>
        </div>
    </form>

</div>
```

**Update:**

Error screen shot

[image]

**Error log**

```
2016-02-02 11:54:24.631 DEBUG 11236 --- [ (self-tuning)'] o.s.s.w.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher   : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/**', GET]
2016-02-02 11:54:24.717 DEBUG 11236 --- [ (self-tuning)'] tRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper : Skip invoking on
2016-02-02 11:54:24.720 DEBUG 11236 --- [ (self-tuning)'] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request '/index.html' matched by universal pattern '/**'
2016-02-02 11:54:24.720 DEBUG 11236 --- [ (self-tuning)'] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Chain processed normally
2016-02-02 11:54:24.720 DEBUG 11236 --- [ (self-tuning)'] o.s.s.w.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher   : Trying to match using NegatedRequestMatcher [requestMatcher=Ant [pattern='/**/favicon.ico']]
2016-02-02 11:54:24.720 DEBUG 11236 --- [ (self-tuning)'] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2016-02-02 11:54:24.726 DEBUG 11236 --- [ (self-tuning)'] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/index.html'; against '/**/favicon.ico'
2016-02-02 11:54:24.727 DEBUG 11236 --- [ (self-tuning)'] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.NegatedRequestMatcher  : matches = true
2016-02-02 11:54:24.727 DEBUG 11236 --- [ (self-tuning)'] o.s.s.w.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher   : Trying to match using NegatedRequestMatcher [requestMatcher=MediaTypeRequestMatcher [contentNegotia
tionStrategy=org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager@3fb33b51, matchingMediaTypes=[application/json], useEquals=false, ignoredMediaTypes=[*/*]]]
2016-02-02 11:54:24.732 DEBUG 11236 --- [ (self-tuning)'] o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : httpRequestMediaTypes=[text/html]
2016-02-02 11:54:24.732 DEBUG 11236 --- [ (self-tuning)'] o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : Processing text/html
2016-02-02 11:54:24.732 DEBUG 11236 --- [ (self-tuning)'] o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : application/json .isCompatibleWith text/html = false
2016-02-02 11:54:24.735 DEBUG 11236 --- [ (self-tuning)'] o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : Did not match any media types
2016-02-02 11:54:24.735 DEBUG 11236 --- [ (self-tuning)'] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.NegatedRequestMatcher  : matches = true
2016-02-02 11:54:24.735 DEBUG 11236 --- [ (self-tuning)'] o.s.s.w.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher   : Trying to match using NegatedRequestMatcher [requestMatcher=RequestHeaderRequestMatcher [expectedHe
aderName=X-Requested-With, expectedHeaderValue=XMLHttpRequest]]
2016-02-02 11:54:24.742 DEBUG 11236 --- [ (self-tuning)'] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.NegatedRequestMatcher  : matches = true
2016-02-02 11:54:24.742 DEBUG 11236 --- [ (self-tuning)'] o.s.s.w.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher   : All requestMatchers returned true
<Feb 2, 2016 11:54:24 AM GMT> <Warning> <HTTP> <BEA-101394> <The exception "The request content-type is not a multipart/form-data" occurred when processing getParameter or getParameterValues from a mu
ltipart value of a ServletRequest.>
2016-02-02 11:54:24.749 DEBUG 11236 --- [ (self-tuning)'] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : DefaultSavedRequest added to Session: DefaultSavedRequest[http://localhost:7001/mdm2/index.html]
2016-02-02 11:54:24.749 DEBUG 11236 --- [ (self-tuning)'] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Calling Authentication entry point.
2016-02-02 11:54:24.749 DEBUG 11236 --- [ (self-tuning)'] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to 'http://localhost:7001/mdm2/login'
2016-02-02 11:54:24.749 DEBUG 11236 --- [ (self-tuning)'] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
2016-02-02 11:54:24.752 DEBUG 11236 --- [ (self-tuning)'] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2016-02-02 11:54:24.755 DEBUG 11236 --- [ (self-tuning)'] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/css/**'
2016-02-02 11:54:24.755 DEBUG 11236 --- [ (self-tuning)'] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/js/**'
2016-02-02 11:54:24.755 DEBUG 11236 --- [ (self-tuning)'] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/images/**'
2016-02-02 11:54:24.755 DEBUG 11236 --- [ (self-tuning)'] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/**/favicon.ico'
2016-02-02 11:54:24.756 DEBUG 11236 --- [ (self-tuning)'] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/error'
2016-02-02 11:54:24.756 DEBUG 11236 --- [ (self-tuning)'] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 1 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFi
lter'
2016-02-02 11:54:24.757 DEBUG 11236 --- [ (self-tuning)'] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 2 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFi
lter'
2016-02-02 11:54:24.757 DEBUG 11236 --- [ (self-tuning)'] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
2016-02-02 11:54:24.757 DEBUG 11236 --- [ (self-tuning)'] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: weblogic.servlet.internal.session.MemorySess
ionData@5cf05b51. A new one will be created.
2016-02-02 11:54:24.760 DEBUG 11236 --- [ (self-tuning)'] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 3 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2016-02-02 11:54:24.760 DEBUG 11236 --- [ (self-tuning)'] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.we
b.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@6b6feeb2
2016-02-02 11:54:24.766 DEBUG 11236 --- [ (self-tuning)'] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 4 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter'
2016-02-02 11:54:24.766 DEBUG 11236 --- [ (self-tuning)'] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 5 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: ''
2016-02-02 11:54:24.767 DEBUG 11236 --- [ (self-tuning)'] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 6 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2016-02-02 11:54:24.767 DEBUG 11236 --- [ (self-tuning)'] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /login' doesn't match 'POST /logout
2016-02-02 11:54:24.769 DEBUG 11236 --- [ (self-tuning)'] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 7 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticati
onFilter'
2016-02-02 11:54:24.769 DEBUG 11236 --- [ (self-tuning)'] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /login' doesn't match 'POST /login
2016-02-02 11:54:24.769 DEBUG 11236 --- [ (self-tuning)'] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 8 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
2016-02-02 11:54:24.772 DEBUG 11236 --- [ (self-tuning)'] o.s.s.w.s.DefaultSavedRequest            : pathInfo: both null (property equals)
2016-02-02 11:54:24.772 DEBUG 11236 --- [ (self-tuning)'] o.s.s.w.s.DefaultSavedRequest            : queryString: both null (property equals)
2016-02-02 11:54:24.772 DEBUG 11236 --- [ (self-tuning)'] o.s.s.w.s.DefaultSavedRequest            : requestURI: arg1=/mdm2/index.html; arg2=/mdm2/login (property not equals)
2016-02-02 11:54:24.772 DEBUG 11236 --- [ (self-tuning)'] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : saved request doesn't match
2016-02-02 11:54:24.775 DEBUG 11236 --- [ (self-tuning)'] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 9 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRe
questFilter'
2016-02-02 11:54:24.775 DEBUG 11236 --- [ (self-tuning)'] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 10 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilt
er'
2016-02-02 11:54:24.781 DEBUG 11236 --- [ (self-tuning)'] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.
AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9056f12c: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@380f4:
 RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: QVyh1Wr7Z0W4Tday2EP8br59ZWpjEKd_6eVwI7-iht4ge-hDwWh1!1907728445!1454414064379; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
2016-02-02 11:54:24.782 DEBUG 11236 --- [ (self-tuning)'] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 11 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
2016-02-02 11:54:24.787 DEBUG 11236 --- [ (self-tuning)'] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 12 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'

2016-02-02 11:54:24.787 DEBUG 11236 --- [ (self-tuning)'] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 13 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2016-02-02 11:54:24.788 DEBUG 11236 --- [ (self-tuning)'] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/login'
2016-02-02 11:54:24.788 DEBUG 11236 --- [ (self-tuning)'] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /login; Attributes: [permitAll]
2016-02-02 11:54:24.788 DEBUG 11236 --- [ (self-tuning)'] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@
9056f12c: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@380f4: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0
:0:1; SessionId: QVyh1Wr7Z0W4Tday2EP8br59ZWpjEKd_6eVwI7-iht4ge-hDwWh1!1907728445!1454414064379; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
2016-02-02 11:54:24.790 DEBUG 11236 --- [ (self-tuning)'] o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@3fe0a47d, returned: 1
2016-02-02 11:54:24.790 DEBUG 11236 --- [ (self-tuning)'] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Authorization successful
2016-02-02 11:54:24.790 DEBUG 11236 --- [ (self-tuning)'] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
2016-02-02 11:54:24.791 DEBUG 11236 --- [ (self-tuning)'] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
<Feb 2, 2016 11:54:24 AM GMT> <Warning> <HTTP> <BEA-101394> <The exception "The request content-type is not a multipart/form-data" occurred when processing getParameter or getParameterValues from a mu
ltipart value of a ServletRequest.>
2016-02-02 11:54:24.797 DEBUG 11236 --- [ (self-tuning)'] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/error'; against '/css/**'
2016-02-02 11:54:24.797 DEBUG 11236 --- [ (self-tuning)'] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/error'; against '/js/**'
2016-02-02 11:54:24.799 DEBUG 11236 --- [ (self-tuning)'] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/error'; against '/images/**'
2016-02-02 11:54:24.799 DEBUG 11236 --- [ (self-tuning)'] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/error'; against '/**/favicon.ico'
2016-02-02 11:54:24.799 DEBUG 11236 --- [ (self-tuning)'] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/error'; against '/error'
2016-02-02 11:54:24.799 DEBUG 11236 --- [ (self-tuning)'] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error has an empty filter list
2016-02-02 11:54:24.803 DEBUG 11236 --- [ (self-tuning)'] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
2016-02-02 11:54:24.805 DEBUG 11236 --- [ (self-tuning)'] tRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper : Skip invoking on
2016-02-02 11:54:24.805 DEBUG 11236 --- [ (self-tuning)'] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Chain processed normally
2016-02-02 11:54:24.805 DEBUG 11236 --- [ (self-tuning)'] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Comment: What is the problem you have? Exception? Error Codes?

Comment: What exactly is the error?

Comment: Do you have a login.jsp or a Controller method mapped to login? Please show that

Comment: @shazin updated with login.html

Comment: Kindly show the controller for spring that has the @Controller that you are using for login. There seems to be a problem with your paths.

Comment: @ochiWlad This is a spring boot app and does not have any (at)Controller. The problem is a bit earlier while loading the login screen and I have nt reach the stage of entering the credentials and authenticating. Thanks.